# How to make django form.errors display only error and not input field affected

Tags: python, django, django-forms

[image]I am using form validation to validate my password to see if they match and it works. However, because `{{ form.errors }}` always return the label of affected input field, i resulted to using the answer provided by [Samsparx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18799377/samsparx) below. however, it does not return errors form my forms.py.

here is my forms.py validation

```
def clean(self):
        super(Signup, self).clean()
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        username = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
        email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
        avatar = self.cleaned_data.get("avatar", False)

        if password != password2:
            self.errors[""] = self.error_class(["Password mismatch"])
```

here is my template

```
<div>
    {% for field in form %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            <p>
                <ul>
                    <li>{{ error }}</li>
                </ul>
            </p><br>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}-->
</div>
```

Whenever i use this above template to return error, it doesn't display the ***Password Mismatch*** error that forms.py returns. If i however use `{{form.errors}}`, it displays the ***Password Mismatch*** error and also displays the label of input field affected which i do not want.

So what i want to know is how do i get `{{form.errors}}` to display any error without displaing label of affect input field.

Comment: Can you also share your html too?

Answer (score 1):

`{{form.errors}}` is a dictionary which save error fields in key value pair. So i solved my problem by looping through it using the code below.

```
{% for key, val in form.errors.items %}
    <p>{{val}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Errors are also listed by field in the form, so you can loop through with this to avoid mentioning the fieldname:

```
{% for field in form %}
   {% for error in field.errors %}
        {{ error }}<br>
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```